# Understanding the real reason behind a Hive failure

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I'm using a JDBC driver to run "describe TABLE_NAME" on hive. It gives me the following error:

```
NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED:
Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

`return code 1` doesn't tell me very much. How do I figure out what the underlying reason is?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because your Hive metastore is not setup properly. Hive uses a RDBMS metastore to store meta data about its tables. This includes things like table names, schemas, partitioning/bucketing/sorting columms, table level statistics, etc.

By default, Hive uses an embedded derby metastore which can only be accessed by one process at a time. If you are using that, it's possible that you have multiple sessions to Hive open that's causing this problem.

In any case, I would recommend you to set up a stand alone metastore for Hive. Embedded derby was chosen for its usability in running tests and a good out of the box metastore. However, in my opinion, it's not fit for production workflows. You can find instructions on how to configure MySQL as Hive metastore [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Hive+Installation#HiveInstallation-ConfiguringtheHiveMetastore).

Comment: I have my metastore set up correctly...that is the first thing I did after running into problems with hive :) AFAICT there is a bug in the JDBC driver.

Comment: What version of Hive are you using? Can you ensure you can connect to the metastore from the same machine as Hive using a different method?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have another sesssion open. Since derby allows only one session per person.
You can check -

```
ps -wwwfu <your id>
```

kill the id which is running the hive connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the table with the name you've specified is didn't exist in the database.
Try creating the table and again run the command. it will work. :)